# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 with 2 arrays of same length

Tags: php, mysql, save

I'm trying to save to a db, and I need to implement a system in which users can specify in which fields of a given table the data has to be saved.

During my tests I had tried the following and everything worked fine:

```
$v = $rowdata; // array with the data to be saved
$r =  "field1,field2,field3"; // fields of the table in which to save
```

Then I prepared the array with the names of the fields and I have put it in the former structure:

```
$v = $rowdata; // data to be saved
$r = $tablefields; // fields of the table to populate
```

But then I get the following message:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I checked with print_r and the two arrays ($rowdata and $tablefields) have the exact same number of elements.
Any idea of why I'm getting this error?

Comment: What does the query look like?

Comment: It would be better if you post the code that creates query. I believe the query is either bad-formed or column count mismatch.

Comment: consider that `count(explode(",",$r))` is `<>` than `count($v)`.
Use `var_dump` and check why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function in php:

```
$r = implode(",", $tablefields);
```

Comment: Thank's so much, now it works! Just one question, I don't get whyfor the data I don't need to use implode, while for the fields I do?

Comment: I can't say as i don't have your complete code, but you can test it with `var_dump` or `echo`  of your final query.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
$r = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');
```